# apache tiles 3 - how to access session scope

Tags: jakarta-ee, tiles, session-scope

I would like to use a ViewPreparer to modify the layout menu, depending on session scope. I don't know how to access the session scope. Inside the view preparer, I implement such method:

```
public void execute(Request tilesContext, AttributeContext attributeContext)
```

I've spent lots of time trying to access the session with no success. Only session-related thing I managed to access is `tilesContext.getAvailableScopes()`. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

please try this:

```
public void execute(Request tilesContext, AttributeContext attributeContext){

HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

HttpSession session = request.getSession();

// your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void execute(Request tilesContext, AttributeContext attributeContext){

    Map<String, Object> request = tilesRequest.getContext("request");

    request.get("{attributeName}"); // this will return your object in request

}
```

u can change request to session if you want to get session attribute.